# several return plotting in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

Try to plot very basic data in R.

```
Year    X1     X2     X3     X4     X5     X6     X7
2004   0.91   0.23   0.28   1.02   0.90   0.95   0.94  
2005   0.57   -0.03  0.88   0.52   0.47   0.55   0.56  
2006   1.30   -0.43  1.95   1.27   1.00   1.19   1.26  
2007   0.44   0.63   0.60   0.34   0.60   0.50   0.46  
2008   1.69   0.34  -2.81  -2.41  -1.80  -1.87  -1.83
```

What I am looking for is a basic line chart over time with `x = year` and `y = value` and the chart itself should include all `X1`-`X7`.

I was looking at the `ggplot2` functionality, but I don't know where to start.

```
# Libraries
library(tidyverse)
library(streamgraph)
library(viridis)
library(plotly)

# Plot
p <- data %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n) +
    geom_area() +
    scale_fill_viridis(discrete = TRUE) +
    theme(legend.position = "none") +
    ggtitle("multiple X over time") +
    theme_ipsum() +
    theme(legend.position = "none")
ggplotly(p, tooltip = "text")
```

Would anyone give me a hand on it, please? Is there an easy way to do it in basic R?

Thanks.

Comment: The `ggplot` is not a *basic* way to make plots in R. You forgot the closing `)` in your `ggplot` call: instead of `ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n)` it has to be `ggplot(aes(x = year, y = n))`.

Comment: @utubun What do you mean by “ggplot is not a basic way to make plots”?

Comment: @KonradRudolph I mean if we stick to the definition of the word **basic**: *simple and not complicated, so able to provide the base or starting point from which something can develop*, it is clear that `ggplot` is not a simplest way to plot data in R, neither it is a starting point for the development of your skills. The simplest way to plot data in R is to use `plot` and related functions from `base` R and `graphics`.

Comment: @utubun [That’s highly debatable](http://varianceexplained.org/r/teach_ggplot2_to_beginners/).

Comment: Kinda, but tidyversing everything in R is also questionable tendency.

Answer (score 1):

It’s unclear what you intend to do with `geom_area` but in the following you’ll see a basic line chart of the data you’ve shown.

The key point is that ‘ggplot2’ works on *tidy data*, so you need to first transform your data into long form:

```
data %>%
    pivot_longer(-Year, names_to = 'Vars', values_to = 'Values') %>%
    ggplot() +
    aes(x = Year, y = Values, color = Vars) +
    geom_line()
```

[image]

Comment: Could you explain please, what is the reason to call `aes()` outside the `ggplot()`? I encounter this kind of style for a first time. `x` as a name for the former variable names is confusing, especially when you read this line `aes(x = Year, y = n, color = x)`.

Comment: @utubun `aes` can go inside or outside of `ggplot`, it makes no difference. I find it more logical to put it outside; I don’t really understand why it’s allowed inside `ggplot` at all. — I agree with you regarding the `x` variable name, but I’m simply going by what OP provided, and all their columns are called `X…`.

Comment: As I said, I have never seen it before. Thanks for clarification.

Comment: @utubun I’ve fixed the names.